# increase size of drawable inside a static content

Tags: java, android, resize, android-drawable

hai i want set a size of a drawable `(i.e Vibrator_Button[i])` i tried using

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
```

and

```
  MarginLayoutParams params = new MarginLayoutParams(width, height);
```

it is not working using all these another headache is it was a static content too, i am wondering how to solve this, the code as follows, any solutions will be really appreciated i apologize this might be a duplicate one but i tried all possible ways.

```
    Cam_Size = 200;
    Segment_Size = 50;
    TextSize = 20;
    Standard_height = 235;

     private static void SetVibratorLayoutDesign() {
                Layout_Frame.removeAllViews();
                Segments = sharedpreferences.getInt(Vars.Selected_Segment_Count, 0);
                int size = Segment_Size + ((16 - (Segments + 1)));
                int imageSize = Cam_Size - Segments;            

                for (int i = 0; i < Segments; i++) {
                    // Create some quick TextViews that can be placed.
                    float angleDeg = i * 360.0f / Segments - 90.0f;
                    float angleRad = (float) (angleDeg * Math.PI / 180.0f);

                    String VibratorName = Vars.Vibrator_On_Off + "_" + i;
                    int Current_State = sharedpreferences.getInt(VibratorName, 0);

                    Vibrator_Button[i] = new ImageButton(act);
                    TextView SegmentName = new TextView(act);
                    Vibrator_Lock[i] = new ImageView(act);
                    SegmentName.setText((i + 1) + "");
                    if (Current_State == 1) {
                        Vibrator_Button[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.calibration_camera_on);
                    } else {
                        Vibrator_Button[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.calibration_camera_off);
                    }
                    Vibrator_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.camera_circle_transparent);
                    Vibrator_Lock[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lock);

                    SegmentName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    SegmentName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    SegmentName.setTextSize(TextSize);
                    SegmentName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    Vibrator_Button[i].setId(Segment_Ids[i]);
                    Vibrator_Lock[i].setId(Segment_Lock_Ids[i]);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(10, 10);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(imageSize, imageSize);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
                    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    lp1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    lp2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

                    Vibrator_Button[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
                    Vibrator_Button[i].setOnClickListener(onClickThis);
                    Vibrator_Lock[i].setLayoutParams(lp2);
                    SegmentName.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    Vibrator_Button[i].setTranslationX(Standard_height * (float) Math.cos(angleRad));
                    Vibrator_Button[i].setTranslationY(Standard_height * (float) Math.sin(angleRad));
                    Layout_Frame.addView(Vibrator_Button[i]);

                    SegmentName.setTranslationX((Standard_height * (float) Math.cos(angleRad)));
                    SegmentName.setTranslationY((Standard_height * (float) Math.sin(angleRad)) - 5);
                    Layout_Frame.addView(SegmentName);

                    Vibrator_Lock[i].setTranslationX((Standard_height * (float) Math.cos(angleRad)));
                    Vibrator_Lock[i].setTranslationY((Standard_height * (float) Math.sin(angleRad)) + 5);
                    Layout_Frame.addView(Vibrator_Lock[i]);

                }
```